# DiskPart "clean" command return "cyclic redundancy error"

Tags: sd-card

I have an 8 GB micro SD card that doesn't work. So I've read that I should run a "clean" command on it in DiskPart. The clean command however returns "DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)".

Any suggestions, or should I just throw away the SD card and buy a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw it away. I couldn't bring it to life in any way. Apparently SD cards just die after a while.